# How to increase the time for an offline password attack

Tags: passwords, hash, javascript, password-cracking, sha

I am trying to answer a CASP exam practice question.

Could someone comment on the options below regarding the logic behind each item? Where is the logical error behind each statement?

> A Storage-as-a-Service company implements both encryption at rest as
>   well as encryption in transit of customers’ data. The security
>   administrator is concerned with the overall security of the encrypted
>   customer data stored by the company servers and wants the development
>   team to implement a solution that will strengthen the customer’s
>   encryption key.
>
> Which of the following, if implemented, will MOST increase the time an
>   offline password attack against the customers’ data would take?

```
A.
key = NULL ; for (int i=0; i<5000; i++) { **key = sha(key + password)** }

B.
password = NULL ; for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) { password = sha256(key) }

C.
password = password + sha(password+salt) + aes256(password+salt)

D.
key = aes128(sha256(password), password))
```

source: various CASP exam cram question banks

---

This is what I know:

1) SHA-256 or higher generates really strong hashes with a very low collision probability. It's highly unlikely to produce a collision.

2) I read another article, but not conclusive regarding the JavaScript option:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279141/javascript-string-encryption-and- 
 decryption

3) This one is much more articulated regarding options to improve the alternatives:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t

4) I found this real example of the SHA256 encoding scheme and as well generating a salt to make it even more secure by defeating precomputed hash tables. We will then run it through password-checking to ensure the password was typed correctly:

```
// From Python: Penetration Testing for Developers

#!/usr/bin/python
import uuid
import hashlib

# Let's do the hashing. We create a salt and append it to the password once hashes.

def hash(password):
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    return hashlib.sha512(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt

# Let's confirm that worked as intended.

def check(hashed, p2):
    password, salt = hashed.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha512(salt.encode() + p2.encode()).hexdigest()

password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
hashed = hash(password)
print('The string to store in the db is: ' + hashed)
re = raw_input('Please re-enter your password: ')

# Let's ensure the passwords matched

if check(hashed, re):
    print('Password Match')
else:
    print('Password Mismatch')
```

Comment: Obviously the answer is A. B doesn't do anything but set `password` to the same value over and over, and C and D are just silly homebrew KDF schemes.

Comment: @forest this is a CASP exam question, can you expand on your explanations as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are overthinking the question. You do not need to understand proper password handling to answer this. Work through each logic flow.

A: You recursively hash `sha(key + password)` `5000 times`, so this increases the work someone has to do to crack it by 5000. Work = 5000

B: You just set `password` to the same value `10000` times, so it is equivalent to just `password = sha256(key)` which is a single hash function. Work = 1

C: The password is not hashed at all, it is left in plaintext with hashes appended to the end. This is obviously the worst possible answer. Work = 0

D: This is a single hash function with 2 steps, so it is a tiny bit better than B, but not really. Work = 1

Comment: Although both `A` and `D` are a bit unclear to me because those are calculating not the hash but the key.  As a result, they are useless without further details on how the key is being used to generate the hashed password...

Comment: @ConorMancone agreed, but I don't think that's the concept being tested in the question